# Проблемы с сортировкой данных с таблицы

Tags: mysql

Хочу отсортировать оружие по точности, но у некоторых из них она индетична. Как мне переделать запрос сортировки, чтобы оружие с большим уроном было выше других, если точность у них  одинаковая?

```
"SELECT `weapon_name`, `weapon_accuracy` FROM `weapon_statistics` ORDER BY  `weapon_accuracy` DESC LIMIT 0, 9"
```

Comment: После ORDER BY перечислить интересующие столбцы через запятую

Comment: Отсортировало по возрастанию. Было по убыванию.

Comment: DESC припишите к интересующим столбцам, очевидно

Comment: Решил проблему. Спасибо